# FreeSWITCH Audio Stream Initialiase

Tags: freeswitch

I am working with FreeSWITCH and trying to understand how audio streams are initialised. I am working with ESL (inbound and outbound) and am trying to record some audio. Through testing i have proven that audio is working correctly for bridged calls, conferences and file playback however not for single legged audio recording - that is, until I play a file first.

In my example the playback application is executed from an outbound socket, the call is then parked and the inbound socket captures the park event and starts recording. With the playback in place i get audio, and without it I simply get a silent file of the correct duration presumably meaning that the the RTP stream is not active.

My question therefore is: How can I initialise the RTP stream for recording, without having played a file first? Is there a command for this, or an argument I can pass to the record application?

My objective is to understand how RTP streams are initialised in FreeSWITCH and any input would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has been answered to some degree in the freeswitch mailing list.

It is possible to play a blank audio stream and so long as the duration is > 500ms you will find the audio stream connected for the record operation. This is the same as playing a blank file prompt.

Execute playback with this as the filename: silence_stream://1000